# Pronoun cases (e.g. "my," "his") before gerund constructions

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, gerunds, personal-pronouns

Which of the following is correct?

> It stands in the way of **my** being successful.

> It stands in the way of **me** being successful.

> This led to **his** succeeding in the workplace.

> This led to **him** succeeding in the workplace.

Comment: They are both correct, the genitive construction ("my/his") being more formal.

Comment: I was always taught that the me/him construction was incorrect because you cannot also write "Me was successful" or "Him succeeded in the workplace." Using the genitive construction of my/his agrees with the gerund forms "being" and "succeeding" since they function as nouns.

Comment: Well, of course you can't write _Me is successful_. That's a tensed clause, not an infinitive. Tensed clauses must have subjects, and they must be nominative. But that's the only use for nominative -- subject of a tensed clause. The subject of an infinitive (which is untensed -- that's what _infinitive_ means) is objective (object of _for_ in the _for..to_ complementizer), and the subject of an _-ing_ clause (either gerund or participle, also untensed) can be either objective (the Acc-_ing_ complementizer) or genitive (the Poss-_ing_ complementizer). But never nominative.

Comment: The point is that these are non-finite clauses functioning as complements, not finite clauses. The only exception with gerund-participials is where the clause is functioning not as a complement but as an adjunct, as in" She sought advice from Ed, [**he/him** being the most experienced of her colleagues]". Here, the pronoun subject can be nominative of accusative.

Comment: @Billj Interesting construction. I would find any pronoun ungrammatical with that, though any personal noun is fine. I.e, *_.., him/he being the most ..._, but _...Ed being the most ..._ is OK. It feels like the extra clause is a separate assertion (hence the comma), and needs to repeat the original NP. I don't quite know why.

Comment: Yes, the comma marks the non-finite adjunct clause as a supplement. The pronoun has "Ed" as antecedent. Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It stands in the way of my being successful*.
>
> *It stands in the way of me being successful.*
>
> *This led to his succeeding in the workplace.*
>
> *This led to him succeeding in the workplace*.

These are all fine.

The personal pronoun subjects of gerund-participial clauses functioning as complement are either genitive case (here, "my/his") or accusative case (here,"me/"him)".

The choice between genitive and non-genitive depends mainly on style: the genitive is characteristic of fairly formal style.